# Can't get launchd plist run successfully in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, launchd

I’m using Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) an learning to use [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) (Launch Daemon) to auto-run some scripts. To make it simple, I decide to use a `shell` script which only contains a `echo` command.

Contents of `hello.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "hello"
```

Also I’ve run `chmod a+x hello.sh` to make it executable and when I run the script manually it works fine.

In `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` I have `com.yang.hello.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.yang.hello</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/yangyy/hello.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

After I run:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yang.hello.plist
```

No error message appears and if I run this command:

```
launchctl list | grep "com.yang.hello"
```

The response I get is:

```
-   78  com.yang.hello.plist
```

It seems that positive number indicates the exit code and the program is not actually running.

Besides, I find something strange when I tried to use `launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yang.hello.plist` to run the program, but when I use this command it returns error and no error message.

What’s wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the exit status of 78 means, but I would not expect this script to do anything detectable when run as a launch agent, because its output is not directed anywhere. When you run it from Terminal, its output is attached to that Terminal window, so that's where the "hello" appears. But launchd has no connection to Terminal (or any other relevant output target), so the "hello" gets discarded. If you want to check whether it's running, you can direct its outputs (both standard output and error output) to files by adding these keys to the .plist (and then unloading and reloading it):

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/yangyy/hello-output.txt</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/Users/yangyy/hello-errors.txt</string>
```

Now, it's also possible that launchd is having some other problem even starting the script. To see if launchd itself is reporting any problems, look in the system log file (`tail -f /var/log/system.log` or run /Applications/Utilities/Console.app), then try to unload+reload the agent and see if anything relevant appears in the log.

Comment: This does help because in the output file there is 'hello'. I thought it would show just in the terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then number you see in `launchctl list` is the status code the daemon-process emitted when it exited.

So, the good news is that the process ran.

Status 78 is a general exit code, so the bad news is that it doesn't tell us much.

Not helping your exact problem, but perhaps spills some light over what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This error for me was being caused by some permission issue caused by my specifying a `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrPath` whose (same) final folder didn't exist. Loading the plist did create the folder, but without giving my user any permissions to it. I chmod'ed, but still got the 78 error code and nothing was being logged to either log file. I didn't see any errors in Console.app either.

I solved the problem by unloading the plist, deleting the automatically-created folder, recreating the folder manually, and then reloading the plist. The daemon is running correctly now, and logs are being written as expected.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/a/1476941/574994 is the correct solution. I have encountered the same problem with the 78 exit code. Turns out that the automatically-created log folder's owner is `root`, and the script can't create log file in it.

Just remove the automatically-create log folder and create it manually and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I solved the problem by doing the inverse of mrwnt10's solution: https://superuser.com/a/1476941/1266379. I had created my out.log file manually with chmod a+w and then loaded my plist - resulting in error 78. But, by deleting the manually created out.log file, unloading and then loading the plist, the out.log file was automatically created and written to successfully.

This was done on macOS Big Sur v11.1

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a suffix in Label string com.yang.hello**.plist**

Try ProgramArguments instead of Program and use two string declaration, first declare path to bash shell and second set your script. For sure define working directory by WorkingDirectory.

For example part of my plist:

```
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/royalcrown/Library/AutoBackup</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>scriptRC.sh</string>
    </array>
```